# Cargar 2 vistas parciales - MVC

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, razor

Tengo un tab con 3 pestañas en donde cada pestaña contiene una vista parcial, entonces cuando yo hago la búsqueda del documento en la pestaña DATOS esta carga información cabecera pero quisiera también poder refrescar la vista parcial DETALLE para que me pueda mostrar su información detalle pero no lo estoy logrando y no tengo muy claro como poder hacerlo, existe alguna opción con jQuery?

1. Mi controlador POST al ser llamado ingresa y ejecuta la búsqueda del documento:

   ```
   public ActionResult CRequerimiento(RequerimientoModelo m, string submitButton)

           Repositorio.Almacen.repo_Requerimiento MostrarDatos = new Repositorio.Almacen.repo_Requerimiento();
                   RequerimientoModelo resultado = MostrarDatos.CargadRQ(m);

                   if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(m.NuDocu))
                   {
                       string mensajeR = "El número de Requerimiento no existe";
                       return RedirectToAction("sO_Requerimiento", new { nuRequerimiento = m.NuDocu, mensajeOK = string.Empty, mensajeKO = mensajeR, sOpcion = "tab_1" });
                   }
                   else
                   {
                       //return PartialView("_DetalleRequerimiento", m);
                       return PartialView("_DatosRequerimiento", m);
   ```
2. Una vez realizada la búsqueda este vuelve a la PartialView DATOS y necesito que también pueda retornar y actualizar la PartialView DETALLES para cargar la información de ahí.

Estoy usando Ajax.BeginForm para llamar a los controladores.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solamente se puede regresar un objeto, entonces regresar múltiples partial views en un return es imposible.

Una alternativa sería cargar toda la página de nuevo, teniendo dentro de ella a las partial views. Si las partial views utilizan diferentes modelos, agrupa dentro de un viewModel a los modelos y ese viewModel es el que le pasarás a la página que agrupa a ambas partial views.

Sería algo parecido a esto:

```
// CONTROLADOR
public ActionResult Accion(ViewModel model)
{
    // validaciones, código extra, etc
    return View("Pagina", model);
}
```

```
// VISTA
<div id="partial1" class="container">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialPage1", model.ModelPartialView1)
</div>
<div id="partial2" class="container">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialPage2", model.ModelPartialView2)
</div>
```

Otra alternativa es crear dos acciones en el controlador, cada una actualizará una partial view y las invocarás utilizando AJAX. Sin embargo, de esta forma tendrías que hacerlo manual (sin Ajax.BeginForm) y tendrías que construir tu objeto a enviar, es decir, todos los datos. Sería algo parecido a esto:

```
public ActionResult PartialView1(ViewModel model)
{
    // validaciones, código extra, etc
    return PartialView("_PartialPage1", model.ModelPartialView1);
}
public ActionResult PartialView2(ViewModel model)
{
    // validaciones, código extra, etc
    return PartialView("_PartialPage2", model.ModelPartialView2);
}
```

y la vista:

```
<div id="partial1" class="container">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialPage1", model.ModelPartialView1)
</div>
<div id="partial2" class="container">
    @Html.Partial("_PartialPage2", model.ModelPartialView2)
</div>

<button type="button" onclick="Update()">Actualizar partial views</button>
@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function Update() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("PartialView1")",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "HTML",
                data: // tus datos,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#partial1").html(data);
                }
            })
            $.ajax({
                url: "@Url.Action("PartialView2")",
                type: "POST",
                datatype: "HTML",
                data: // tus datos,
                success: function (data) {
                    $("#partial2").html(data);
                }
            });
        }
    </script>
}
```

Comment: Me parece que tomaré la primera alternativa, una última consulta puedo tener implementado Ajax.BeginForm y Html.BeginForm en una misma vista parcial? Para tener en los casos que quiera actualizar toda la página y para otro cuando solo quiera actualizar un parte.

Comment: Ambos genera etiquetas form, que por su naturaleza no permite estar anidados. Podrías encapsular tu vista en un Htm.BeginForm y debajo de ese bloque utilizar un Ajax.BeginForm pero tendrías que desencadenar los submit manualmente utilizando botones con type="button" en lugar de elementos de type="submit". Espero haberte ayudado, no olvides votar las respuestas. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias, ya apliqué la primera opción y me funciona.